# declare this property in your class or use a local variable

Tags: variables, local

excuse my English
I am presenting an extension on phpbb, but this has been **rejected for this**.

***Line 25: please declare this property in your class or use a local variable.***

I can not figure out what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would like you to declare the properties before using them like this:

```
class banner_scroll_module
{
    public $u_action;
    private $table;

    function main($id, $mode)
    {
        ...
        $this->table = $table_prefix . 'banner';
    }
}
```

Or, if they will only be used within that function you can just use local variables:

```
class banner_scroll_module
{
    public $u_action;

    function main($id, $mode)
    {
        ...
        $table = $table_prefix . 'banner';
    }
}
```

Note that they will also want you to fix `$tpl_name` and `$page_title`

In response to your second question (which shouldn't be asked in an answer I believe) you need to free the result like this:

```
$this->$db->sql_freeresult($result_banner);
```

Comment: Thanks friend ^_^

Comment: Certainly I also gave the points, but how do I accept the answer?